# How to spawn objects (boxes) with a certain logic in Unreal Engine 4 WITHOUT blueprints?

Tags: game-development, unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5

I am new to ue4, so the question may be easy or have a tutorial that I couldn't find:)

I have a world in ue4 (imported) which is static. I want to add some boxes (with different pictures on each) which will spawn/despawn from the world at certain times and locations. How would I do that in a project without blueprints? A link to a tutorial or an explanation would be very much appreciated.

In addition, I would like some of the boxes to move in a simple "patrol". In this too, any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

To spawn an actor, just call SpawnActor method

```
 auto myActor = GetWorld()->SpawnActor<MyActorType>(MyActorType::StaticClass(), location, rotation, spawnParameters);
```

It returns a pointer to the spawned entity: if you want to update it, just keep it and then at every tick set a new position/orientation

```
myActor->SetActorLocationAndRotation(
    newPosition,
    newOrientation,
    false,
    nullptr,
    ETeleportType::None
);
```